# How to Monitor data or Structs in memory in Go

Tags: go

I want to create a project or package that loads data (maybe 1 or 2 million items) in memory. I want to monitor this data and know if this data is well on memory, exist or no. In Java this can be done with JMX (Java Management Extensions) but in Golang I do not know how do it.

I want to do this in a **production environment**, not just a testing environment.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: can you show an example of the data?

Comment: e.g. Nodes of a binary tree, the binary tree that I am using is [treap](https://github.com/stathat/treap) or maybe an array with 1 million of struct.

Comment: Can you clarify what this means:  "know if this data is well on memory, exist or no".  Do you mean how much memory is being used?

Comment: @kristianp The idea like you said is "know if this data is well on memory, exist or no, and verify its content"

Answer (score 2):

You can use `os.GetUsage` to track memory usage. You can then either use a statsd client or direct UDP messages to update graphite (or whatever monitoring package you like).

You might also find this article [Monitoring a Production Golang Server with Memstats](https://errplane.com/blog/monitoring-a-production-golang-server-with-memstats) helpful.